# IBM Watson Tone Analyzer Invalid JSON Error

Tags: json, curl, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I must be missing something very simple here.  I am following the [Example Tutorial Instructions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tone-analyzer/index.html#generalPurposePost). I already created a free account and I have my API key and the URL. I copied the JSON file as instructed.  Here is the command I issued:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:MY-API-KEY" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data-binary PATH-TO-FILE \
"MY-URL"
```

- Where **MY-API-KEY** equals my personal key specified on my Manage page.
- Where **PATH-TO-FILE** equals the path to my local copy of tone.json
- Where **MY-URL** equals the url specified on my Manage page.

Here is the error I am getting:

> {"code":400,"sub_code":"C00012","error":"Invalid JSON input at line 1, column 2"}

I copied the JSON exactly from the directions:

```
{
  "text": "Team, I know that times are tough! Product sales have been disappointing for the past three quarters. We have a competitive product, but we need to do a better job of selling it!"
}
```

I also attempted the following JSON and it received the same error:

```
{"text":"Hello world"}
```

What obvious thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was going to be something silly.

The directions have this as an example:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:{apikey}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data-binary @{path_to_file}tone.json \
"{url}/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21"
```

For the path to the file, I had to keep the `@` symbol in front. so let's assume the full path to the file is `/home/joe/Desktop/tone.json`, that line has to be:

```
--data-binary @/home/joe/Desktop/tone.json \
```